# Получение интервала в удобоваримом виде?

Tags: postgresql

Хочу проверить, когда была внесена последняя запись в базу.

Запрос

```
SELECT   localtimestamp - "F_Date"
```

Приходит что-то вида 00:00:09.454646

Как избавится от микросекунд в конце?

Comment: попробуйте `CAST (localtimestamp - "F_Date" AS int)`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT (localtimestamp - "F_Date")::interval(0)
```